# Best SEO software for comparing two pages

Tags: seo

Hi I am looking for software that can help me compare metrics of two pages on the web, targeting the same keyword. So if my page is on position 5 in Google I would want to analyse the no.1 spot holder and see what internal and external factors are putting the other page in front of mine. Thanks

Comment: http://www.opensiteexplorer.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to SEOmoz (http://www.seomoz.org/) They are the number one in seo, you can sign up for a free trial and use there tools. And use their on page analysis tool. http://pro.seomoz.org/tools/on-page-keyword-optimization/new its the best on the web. i have used enough of them for my job. It will tell you everything you need to know and more between that tool and the rest of their tools.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to be more specific and say that I use [Website Auditor](http://www.link-assistant.com/website-auditor/) and [SEO Spyglass](http://www.link-assistant.com/seo-spyglass/) for competition analysis.

Website Auditor is for *on-page SEO*, it shows you the structure of a site, shows you how the keyword/s are used in titles, site copy, anchor texts, etc. It also scans top 10 competitors and prompts the best way to optimize content.

If you'd like to compare 2 sites, you can start a separate project for each site, but analyze them against the same keyword/set of keywords.

Now, SEO Spyglass is an *off-page tool*. It lets you check backlinks for different URLs. So, again, you can create 2 projects and compare backlinks to two websites.

Answer (score 0):

[SEO Moz](http://www.seomoz.org/) is probably what you want.

[Raven Tools](http://raventools.com/) might be more your speed, but I don't have any experience with their toolset.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure [ColibriTool](http://colibritool.com) would do the job :) It provides many statistics about traffic, backlinks, conversion for your sites but also for competitor's sites.

Answer (score 0):

I've used Market Samurai with some great success before. I'm not 100% sure it will do what you want(and this question is like a year old) but anyone else who is looking for a good keyword tool or content generator. Hope this helps someone!

(I don't work for them or anything. Just a pretty user-friendly interface)

http://www.marketsamurai.com/